# Simplifying ERD with potential null and repeated values

Tags: mysql, database-normalization, erd

I am currently creating an Entity Relationship Diagram for a project but it seems to look strange. 
I feel like there must be a better way to store the data to avoid repeated values or multiple NULL values but can't quite seem to figure how.

---

The project is a website that allows users to request their own forum which is then approved and added to the site.

Other times, administrators can create forums between themselves by skipping the request stage.

I have 3 tables:

- Users
- Requests
- Forums

**Users** table stores the administrators and subscribers (using a role field).

**Requests** table stores the requested forum title and user, as well as whether this was approved and who by if so.

**Forums** table stores the active forums with their URL, the ID of the administrator, which admin user created the actual page, and if created from a request then request_id.

Here is how the model looks at the minute:
[Entity Relationship Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ial04.png)

---

The issues I see are related to forums that are created without requests, the **request_id** field in **Forums** would be NULL if there was no request. 
Also, if the forum IS associated with a request, then the user_id field will be duplicated in both the **Forums** and **Requests** table.

Can anyone see any problems with keeping it this way or whether there are better ways to model this?

Comment: You can add a "forum_id" to the request-table that will get filled when a forum gets created by a request. On the other hand, don't be scared of the `null`. `null` is a perfectly fine value which you can use exactly as it is right now: "there was no request for this forum". For your double user id: I would assume it is possible to change the admin for a forum at a later point (e.g. if he stops to come online or you ban him or something else). So it's perfectly fine to have a different column for that.

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare, I appreciate the feedback.
So is it OK in the **Forums** table for each record to have _either_ **request_id** or **user_id** if it was assumed that the admin user would not change (as it would get deleted if that user is no longer the admin)?
Then the user_id can be retrieved from the related request?

Comment: I would not do that. The user in `request` is something different than the admin in `forum`. Technically it's correct and will work, but it feels more complicated than it has to be and you asked for simplification. Maybe I underestimate the importance of your request table in your process. You could use the same table for requests and forums and mark requests by a column `not approved yet` (which, for admin-created forums is not set). Then the user-column will have the same meaning in both cases. But if that makes sense depends on what else you do with requests and forums differently.